# Is there any difference between ConvNet and CNN?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, terminology

ConvNet stands for Convolutional Networks and CNN stands for Convolutional Neural Networks.

Is there any difference between both?

If yes, then what is it?

If no, is there any reason behind using ConvNet at some places and CNN at some other places in literature?

Comment: it's the same, networks are almost always neural networks in DL

Answer (score 7):

Both terms just mean *convolutional neural network*. I don't believe there is any particular reason to choose one over the other: ConvNet is slightly easier to say out loud and CNN is slightly shorter to write, but there is absolutely no difference in meaning.

For some contrasting examples in the literature, the [EfficientNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11946) paper chooses the term ConvNet and [this paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2012/file/c399862d3b9d6b76c8436e924a68c45b-Paper.pdf) on AlexNet chooses CNN. They are talking about the same sorts of neural networks though!